# How much the memory limitation is on the iOS device browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, frontend, webkit

My webpage embeds too many iframes, which leads my webpage to crash in the iOS device browser

I want to know how much the iOS webpage memory limitation is.

Comment: Do you mean Safari web browser?

Comment: yes,I mean Safari, but I find out whatever browser is, they all crash down, so I guess it is because of those browsers implemented based on Webkit

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the memory limit on iOS Safari is rather low. It’s limited to **384MB** on version 15, it’s lower on earlier versions, and it’s probably device specific as well.

As I said it depends on the device as well but it's always between **200-400MB**.

Comment: thank you so much, by the way is there has any documents I can see about the memory limitation

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately there isn't any official document on the internet and the numbers are experimental that are calculated by developers. (Because of this we don't have the exact number of memory limit).
Also please select my answer as the correct answer if possible. Thanks.