# Three JS : Cannot load a high detailed 3D Model

Tags: node.js, import, three.js, 3d, gltf

As a non-specialist designer, I don't precisely know every technical specification of 3D environnement,
for work purpose we tried various experiment with importing glTF assets.

On Three JS we used the beginner's package that load a specific objet into your project's folder and have some mouse control to see how's it feel,

We realized that on Three JS :

Loading 384 149Ko, 4 208 360 triangles -> It's Ok
Loading 856 085Ko, 9 258 394 triangles -> The page is displayed but it seems that the moddle ins't displayed on the scene, or not loaded at all (With a smaller objet, we had 48 fps, with a bigger moddle we have 60 fps and don't have any display)

We don't really know what happens during the process,

We tried to find  any technical informations on Three JS, there isn't any precise information on importing huge assets on Three JS, we learned that tha navigator have specifications too, but stil no precise informations ..

Do you have any idea of what happens ?
Is there any "max size" specification somewhere ?
Or is it some kind of internal instability ?
Is there any way to get technical information ?
And last but not least : Does it exist any other way to import huge assets on Three JS ?

Our mind are open on any source of information that would exists ..

Edit : With new trials, it seems that when I try uploading a too huge 3D Moddle, a classic 3D viewport gonna be slow, but three JS instead throw me on the screen : Something went wrong while displaying this webpage Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT
It happens at a relative random perçentage of progression, and there isn't simple way to get extra details of the error,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  Also look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Don's answer is great and provides some good insights, but your question needs more focus. and more details. Focus on the problem of loading and rendering the data (specifically requesting external resources is outside the scope of Stack Overflow). If you're using a desktop, open your browser's developer console to see if any errors were emitted while loading the file that isn't working. You may find something as simple as a 404 error is preventing you from loading the file. And if you do see errors, add them to your question.

Comment: Is the whole page crashing? How big is this glTF file? It sounds like you're hitting a memory wall in the browser, rather than anything going on in three.js.

Comment: Exactly, when the app start loading the mesh file, I got a progression log (1%, 2%, etc.) on the console and the page instantly crash when the loading stop progressing.
We make different trials with various sizes of files, but the referencial glTF is about 1.5 Go
I know this is a inefficient way to use asset, I only need the factual proof of the part (Navigator, three js, etc.) which break during the process

Comment: Again, this is dependent on your browser. 1.5Gb would eventually load on a desktop, but a mobile device would be much more limited, and may very well fail bringing such a large file into memory. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506298/how-much-the-memory-limitation-is-on-the-ios-device-browser). So, whatever your platform/browser combination is, look for the JavaScript memory limits imposed by that combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no hard limit – it depends on your device, too. But a common rule of thumb is to use < 100,000 triangles if you want your scene to run well on mobile devices, and only carefully go above that. Textures with high resolution will take up a lot of memory (much more than their size on disk) and are a huge contributor too.

You might also find the [Realtime Asset Guidelines](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/3DC-Asset-Creation/blob/main/asset-creation-guidelines/RealtimeAssetCreationGuidelines.md) from Khronos helpful. Those guidelines were written for retail / e-commerce companies bringing models of products into 3D scenes, and are not WebGL-specific, but think it's a pretty decent starting point for any realtime 3D scene.

Excerpt:

- **File Size:** Ideally less than 5MB. Note that as glTF geometry and texture compression extensions, such as glTF Universal Textures using the KTX container and geometry compression using Draco, ... smaller assets or more visual fidelity at the same asset size will be possible.
- **Draw calls:** should be minimized by consolidating meshes, and using fewer materials.
- **Triangle Count:** 100,000 triangles or less.
- **Texture Aspect Ratio:** use power of 2 resolutions, square aspect ratio is not required.
- **Texture Size:** Use 1024⨉1024 (1K) or 2048⨉2048 (2K) for BaseColor, ORM and Emissive maps. 2K is recommended for Normal maps which are more sensitive to reduced resolutions than even Albedo maps. Normals Maps are also severely sensitive to JPG artifacts - a 2K JPG giving the same quality as same as 1K PNG normal map.

I would expect 10M vertices in WebGL to be slow, on most of today's devices. Most applications and games — even those not using WebGL — use various graphics tricks to create a highly detailed *appearance* without requiring that many vertices at runtime. For example, baking details into normal maps on a low-poly mesh, or using LODs to render less-detailed versions of distant objects.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing,

Could we consider these information as "official" standard ?

It seems that three JS has a limit somewhere,

When I try uploading a too huge 3D Moddle, a classic 3D viewport gonna be slow, but three JS instead throw me on the console :

(Relative random percentage) 40.82992961930753% loaded

And the screen :
Something went wrong while displaying this webpage
Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

Depending on your spec, it seems that the used file (1.5 GB, millions of triangles, 40 K independant objects) I used if so far away from the recommandation ..

Comment: @Heolu Like Don said, it's going to depend on your device. I have personally seen desktop browsers load more than 20million (indexed) triangles. Mobile devices are by nature more limited. That said, there is no "official standard" for WebGL/three.js. The browser will support what the browser will support. Maybe a clever developer can squeeze some extra performance if they handle their data differently, or write their own shaders, but in the end there is no documented  "official" threshold.

Comment: I think if your model is within those limits, the model is unlikely to be the cause of a performance issue. As @TheJim01 mentions, good developers can break these rules – but to do that you have measure things carefully and work around issues, and it becomes more of a technical puzzle than a set of fixed rules.